# How can I see how many different people I have contacted in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, google-contacts, contacts

In Gmail you have a conversation mode, but just counting the amount of conversations doesn't work since there are often mistakes in there. Also, emails to myself are often in there as well.

Is there a way to see how many people (i.e. different email addresses) I have contacted?

Comment: Doubt there is a native way to do this. @pnuts has a good idea. If your history is too large to count manually, you could probably find a way to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Using third party software

One option is to use a tool such as [Email Address Extractor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/email-address-extractor/kafpofaomkigncgeihallnooonbkdbpa) which is a Chrome extension. Using Google's [filters](https://digitalinspiration.com/gmail-search-4355), you can generate a list of data and export it to a CSV. You can then manipulate that data in Excel or Google Sheets to get the desired results. For example, you can have a list of every email that was sent, or a list of unique email addresses that you have sent to.

### Using Google contacts

By default, whenever an email is sent from the gmail, that address gets added to the **All Contacts** or **Other Contacts** list of [Google Contacts](http://www.google.com/contacts). You can export a list by doing the following:

1. Navigate to http://www.google.com/contacts/. Log in if necessary.
2. From the left menu, click **More** and select **Export**.
3. If prompted, to export from the old version, click **Go to old version**.
4. Another tab will open. From the left menu, click **Other Contacts**.
5. From the top of the screen, click the □ arrow to expand the list. (Located to the left of **Add to My Contacts**.)
6. From the list, click **All**.
7. Click the **More** arrow and select **Export**.
8. Choose the appropriate details and click **Export**.